# Traceability Matrix

Tags: cross-referencing, xint

My aim is to build an automatic Traceability Matrix at the end of my document. For that, I define all requirements to be validated at first and after, in different sections which one is tested.

The code is based on [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220561/automate-generation-of-table-from-data-in-enumerated-lists), but I'd like to simplify this with an automatic generation of label name, and for that, I want to use a counter.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\requirements}{}
\providecommand*\phantomsection{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\req}[1]{%
  \textbf{R#1}%
  \phantomsection
  \def\@currentlabel{R#1}%
  \label{req@#1}%
  \g@addto@macro\requirements{{req@#1}}%
  \global\@namedef{req@#1@ismetby}{}%
}

\newcommand{\meetsreq}[1]{%
  \ref{req@#1}%
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname req@#1@ismetby\expandafter\endcsname 
              \expandafter {\expandafter{\@currentspec}}%
}

\newcommand{\specswithreq}[1]% 
% The space before \ref below is intentional and will be swallowed by \xintApply
% It is not mandatory however, the thing works without it too.
 {\xintListWithSep{, }{\xintApply { \ref}{\csname #1@ismetby\endcsname }}}

\newcommand{\spec}[1]{\label{spec@#1}\gdef\@currentspec{spec@#1}}
% (update Jan 5, to use \gdef rather than \def in \spec, allowing more flexible usage; has its pros and cons)
\makeatother

\usepackage{xinttools}

\usepackage{hyperref}% check if ok with hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\newcounter{argcnt}\setcounter{argcnt}{0}


\begin{document}


\section{Requirement LIST}

[\req{R1}] requirement 1

[\req{R2}] requirement 2

[\req{R3}] requirement 3

[\req{R4}] requirement 4

[\req{R5}] requirement 5

[\req{R6}] requirement 6


\section{section1}
\setcounter{argcnt}{1}
\spec{1}  Test 1 covert : \meetsreq{R1} \meetsreq{R2}

\section{section2}
\setcounter{argcnt}{2}  
\spec{\theargcnt} Test 2 covert : \meetsreq{R4} \meetsreq{R2}

\section{section3}
\setcounter{argcnt}{3} 
\spec{3} Test 3 covert : \meetsreq{R6}

\section{section4}
\setcounter{argcnt}{4}  
\spec{4} Test 4 covert : \meetsreq{R2}, \meetsreq{R3}

\section{Tracability MAtrix}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Requirement & Specification   \\ 
\hline
\xintFor* #1 in \requirements\do {\ref{#1}&\specswithreq{#1}\\
                                  \hline }%
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Like you can see in the picture the generation with the counter function doesn't work. The Matrix doesn't link the correct test to the good requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\newcommand{\spec}[1]{\label{spec@#1}\def\@currentspec{spec@#1}}`

will use the argument `#1`, in this case `\theargcount`. This is evaluated too late here, you need the value (or expansion) of `\theargcount` in the very moment `\spec` is applied, i.e. use `\xdef\@currentspec{spec@#1}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\requirements}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\req}[1]{%
  \textbf{R#1}%
  \phantomsection
  \def\@currentlabel{R#1}%
  \label{req@#1}%
  \g@addto@macro\requirements{{req@#1}}%
  \global\@namedef{req@#1@ismetby}{}%
}

\newcommand{\meetsreq}[1]{%
  \ref{req@#1}%
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname req@#1@ismetby\expandafter\endcsname 
              \expandafter {\expandafter{\@currentspec}}%
}

\newcommand{\specswithreq}[1]% 
% The space before \ref below is intentional and will be swallowed by \xintApply
% It is not mandatory however, the thing works without it too.
 {\xintListWithSep{, }{\xintApply { \ref}{\csname #1@ismetby\endcsname }}}

\newcommand{\spec}[1]{\label{spec@#1}\xdef\@currentspec{spec@#1}}
% (update Jan 5, to use \gdef rather than \def in \spec, allowing more flexible usage; has its pros and cons)
\makeatother

\usepackage{xinttools}

\usepackage{hyperref}% check if ok with hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\newcounter{argcnt}\setcounter{argcnt}{0}


\begin{document}


\section{Requirement LIST}

[\req{R1}] requirement 1

[\req{R2}] requirement 2

[\req{R3}] requirement 3

[\req{R4}] requirement 4

[\req{R5}] requirement 5

[\req{R6}] requirement 6


\section{section1}
\setcounter{argcnt}{1}
\spec{1}  Test 1 covert : \meetsreq{R1} \meetsreq{R2}

\section{section2}
\setcounter{argcnt}{2}  
\spec{\theargcnt} Test 2 covert : \meetsreq{R4} \meetsreq{R2}

\section{section3}
\setcounter{argcnt}{3} 
\spec{3} Test 3 covert : \meetsreq{R6}

\section{section4}
\setcounter{argcnt}{4}  
\spec{4} Test 4 covert : \meetsreq{R2}, \meetsreq{R3}

\clearpage
\section{Tracability MAtrix}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Requirement & Specification   \\ 
\hline
\xintFor* #1 in \requirements\do {\ref{#1}&\specswithreq{#1}\\
                                  \hline }%
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```